# Reaction mechanism with benzylchloride (KMnO4 and Soda lime)

Tags: reaction-mechanism

[image]

So I know that $\ce{KMnO4}$ converts any side chain irrespective of chain length to -$\ce{COOH}$ group and Soda lime converts that into the respective alkane. But in benzyl chloride, the alkyl group side chain also has a chlorine atom attached. How would the mechanism proceed?

It is given that Benzene is the product.

Comment: You have water present, benzyl chloride is a reactive species. Consider the possibility that the benzyl chloride hydrolyses to benzyl alcohol early in the reaction

Comment: @Waylander Ok, but then how would KMnO4 react with a side chain containing alcohol?

Comment: Alcohol to acid is a std permangate oxidation

Comment: @Waylander Ah i haven't gotten to that part i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a magical reaction. Yet, it is a two step reaction as depicted in diagram below:

[image: Decarboxylation]

As @Waylander's comment elsewhere, benzyl chloride might have converted to benzyl alcohol before get oxidized to benzoic acid in acidic $\ce{KMnO4}$ solution (the first step). This oxidation is well known [(see here)](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Basic_Principles_of_Organic_Chemistry_(Roberts_and_Caserio)/15%3A_Alcohols_and_Ethers/15.06%3A_Oxidation_of_Alcohols). The second step is heating (may be $\gt \pu{200 ^\circ C}$) of solid benzoic acid in the presence of solid soda lime to cause the decarboxylation. This reaction is well described by [Dr. Jim Clark (here)](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/acids/decarbox.html) and [also here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Carboxylic_Acids/Reactivity_of_Carboxylic_Acids/The_Decarboxylation_of_Carboxylic_Acids_and_Their_Salts).

Comment: Acid permanganate oxidation of alcohols is mentioned here  https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Basic_Principles_of_Organic_Chemistry_(Roberts_and_Caserio)/15%3A_Alcohols_and_Ethers/15.06%3A_Oxidation_of_Alcohols

Comment: @Waylander: I included your site in my answer. Thank you for the insight! :-)